# equivalent code of 'open with' in python script

Tags: python, tkinter, equivalent

[image: open a file in python tkinter app]

```
import sys
sys. argv[1]
```

is the code equivalent of the above image. Please reply me

Comment: TL;DR: No it does not. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/ . What is your goal?

Comment: To pass a file path to my tkinter app . When I will click on this file and try to open via my tkinter application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer. yes it is right I wanted to create a pdf reader application using python tkinter which i will use to open any pdf file. When i will click a pdf file it will show my tkinter app and i will open it via my pdf app this tkinter app will show that pdf file.And finally i successfully completed it. This is full code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
import os
import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry('630x700+400+100')
root.title('Python Pdf Reader')
root.configure(bg='white')
try:
    filepath = str(sys.argv[1])

except:
    filepath = ''
v2 = pdf.ShowPdf().pdf_view(root, pdf_location=filepath,
                            width=77, height=100)


def browseFiles():
    global v2
    try:
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                              title="Select pdf file",
                                              filetypes=(('PDF File', '.pdf'),
                                                         ('PDF file', '.PDF'),
                                                         ('All file', '.txt')))

        v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
        v1.img_object_li.clear()
        v2.destroy()
        v2 = v1.pdf_view(root, pdf_location=filename,
                         width=77, height=100)
        v2.pack(pady=(0, 0))

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'{e}')


Button(root, text='Open', command=browseFiles, width=40, font='arial 20', bd=4).pack()

v2.pack(pady=(0, 0))

root.mainloop()
```

And when you will build this code into windows installer and install this in your windows pc. You will get that result. This is my details answer so share this answer. I think it will really help anybody

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `os` which is in-built library to Python. Then you can use

```
os.startfile(_filepath_)
```

to open the file.

Comment: I also tried it
It doesn't work to me